# React redux and firebase remove onAuthStateChanged listener

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, firebase-authentication, redux-thunk

Im using React, Redux and Firebase to Authenticate user.

I have added into my component lifecycle ComponentWillMount

dispatch(onAuthStateChanged()) to execute this listener.

and my actions with middleware thunk

```
export const onAuthStateChanged = () => dispatch => {
  auth.onAuthStateChanged(
    () => {
      dispatch({ type: CURRENT_USER, currentUser: auth.currentUser });
    },
    error => {
      //system error
    }
  );
};
```

Does anyone know how I would get around to removing this listener with componentWillUmount??

Comment: which version of react you using ?

Comment: @VISHALDAGA React 16+

Comment: Is it better to have onAuthStateChanged be called directly in the component and assign the function to a variable which i can call later in componentWillUmount to remove the listener. Rather than having the redux dispatch an action to call this function?